# different layout for iPad air 2 and iPad pro

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, size-classes

I use size class wR hR for adjusting the layout for iPad. It turns out fine for iPad air 2 but still not satisfactory for iPad pro. It is very big. I don't know how to further refine the constraints for iPad pro.

Any thought about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iPad Pro is also `wR hR`, so you're not going to be able to differentiate by any change in Interface Builder. If you want things to be different on the iPad Pro, you'll have to make those adjustments in code based on the screen size.